# Rails deployment and hosting - reseller rather than DigitalOcean or similar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, hosting

I'm a little confused with how deployment of an application works.

I've been looking up tutorials and numerous times it is suggested that it goes live with DigitalOcean, Heroku or something similar, but some are monthly payment services (albeit not a large amount).

I resell hosting to my clients when I build websites for them so I manage everything on my side. My question is: is there a way to deploy a Rails app to my own web hosting space rather than having to use a third-party service? Have I missed something in the documentation?

I'm certain that my hosting can support everything that's needed. If anyone could explain how or why not I'd really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the stack on your own server without problems. When you are using apache or nginx, the easiest might be to use passenger for serving your rails application.
You just need to make sure you have the right ruby version and bundler installed. Services like DO are just simpler to work with as they already do all the needed server setup and most of the configuration for you.